# Snow Leopard - Finder "Arrange By ..." for all files/folders

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, file-management, finder

I just upgraded to Snow Leopard and one feature that seems to be different (from Leopard) is that setting the default "arrange by" option doesn't affect all files and folders, and only changes the currently open folder.

Is there a way to do this so these settings stay persistent for all files and folders?

Comment: Mmh seems to work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Just a follow-up for anyone reading this.

I found this kind of behaviour happened when I had previously set the default view settings for multiple folders.  It just didn't seem to save my changes.  I'm now running 10.6.3 and this appears to be functioning normally.

I can now select my home or Applications directory and set default view settings for all folders, and it sticks.